# How to automount into specific directories?

Tags: linux, mount, opensuse

I'm using openSUSE 12.2 with KDE3. When I connect my portable hard drive it gets automatically mounted in /media/XXXXXXX, where XXXXXXXX is just some random identifier. How can I control mounting of a hard drive so it gets mounted to /media/disk ? Previously I used openSUSE 11.3 and it always mount my disk in that directory and I don't know what setting was responsible for this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the appropriate setting. In Konqueror go to system:/media, right-click a device and then Properties -> Mounting -> Mountpoint allows to specify mounting location.